# bash: daemonizing by forking process as a new child

Tags: linux, bash, daemon

I have a bash script which should *daemonize* itself after being run. My solution looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh -xe
child() {
    echo child
}
child & # fork child
echo parent
kill $$ # kill parent
```

However, putting the whole script itself inside the function `child` does not seem the correct thing to do. Unfortunately `exec &` won't fork-off the whole process into a backgrounded child.

How can a achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$_IS_DAEMON" ]; then
    _IS_DAEMON=1 /bin/bash $0 "$@" &
    exit
fi

echo "I'm a deamon!"
```

The script effectively restarts itself in the background, while exiting the script started by user.

To recognize the daemonization *status*, it uses an environment variable (the `$_IS_DAEMON` in the example above): if not set, assume started by user; if set, assume started as part of daemonization.

To restart itself, the script simply invokes `$0 "$@"`: the `$0` is the name of the script as was started by the user, and the `"$@"` is the arguments passed to the script, preserved with white-spaces and all (unlike the `$*`). I also typically call needed shell explicitly, as to avoid confusion between `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` which are on most *nix systems are not the same.

Comment: @Inian, expanded answer.

Comment: That explains it! Great answer!

Comment: Note that though I specify `/bin/bash` explicitly, the trick would work with other shells too. The only problem is with the shells which do not support `"$@"` (or alternatives) to pass the arguments verbatim to the subshell. But outside some commercial *nix systems with very old `/bin/sh`, you shouldn't have problems.